# Can i use ui-sref to call ui-router state using URL and parameters?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

we have three pages in our app which can be classified under one parent page  as below.

```
1)Parent
  I)Child1
  II)Child2
  III)ChildIII

.state('Parent', {
            url: '/Parent/:ID',
            templateUrl: 'parent.html',
controller:'parentcontroller'
        })
.state('Parent.Child1', {
            url: '/Child1',
            templateUrl: 'Child1.html'
        })
.state('Parent.Child2', {
            url: '/Child2',
            templateUrl: 'Child2.html'
        })
.state('Parent.Child3', {
            url: '/Child3',
            templateUrl: 'Child3.html'
        })
```

sometimes we need to call this child pages sequentially one after another from child1 to child3 without parameters and sometimes we need to call those child pages individually but requests needs to go through parent controller so that we do not have to instantiate new controller instance for each one of those child pages. to accomplish this i'm using `href` but i want to be able to call parent and child with out passing  any params.
**working href ex:** `<a href='../Parent/{{ID}}/child1'`
**Not working ex:** `<a href='../Parent/child1'`

can anyone please guide me to accomplish this?? Thanks!!

solution:

```
 .state('Parent', {
                url: '/Parent/:ID',
                templateUrl: 'parent.html',
    controller:'parentcontroller',
               params:{ID:null}
            })
    .state('Parent.Child1', {
                url: '/Child1',
                templateUrl: 'Child1.html'
            })
    .state('Parent.Child2', {
                url: '/Child2',
                templateUrl: 'Child2.html'
            })
    .state('Parent.Child3', {
                url: '/Child3',
                templateUrl: 'Child3.html'
            })

From HTML:<a ui-sref="(Parent.Child1{ID:{{value}}})">Home</a>
```

i wasn't aware that if we use `SREF` as above and controller declared at parent value can still read the `params` but gave a shot and it worked!!

Comment: What do you mean "sometimes we need to call this child pages sequentially one after another from child1 to child3"? Should each page use the same controller?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused about what you're asking, but the way it sounds is that all the pages use the same controller. If that's the case, just let them. Controllers will eventually be destroyed when they are no longer needed, so instantiating a new one is fine. If you're routing to a new page, it's going to look for the accompanying controller.

### --Edit based on OP's comment--

If the goal is to only get data once, you can store that in a service. Every service is a singleton, so if you grab data and save it in your service, you can inject that service elsewhere and have access to it.

Comment: sorry for the confusion..actually, I was leaning towards to instantiate controller only once so that i can have all the data in single scope and moreover these pages are like widget so if user goes back data will be populated..i figured the solution after seeing with fresh eyes..updated the comment

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. First you should define your params in your *.state()*, if you are passing params to **child1** state, then it should defined by like below,

```
.state('Parent.Child1', {
    url: '/Child1',
    templateUrl: 'Child1.html',
    params: {
        paramName: ''  //here paramName can be named by your wish.
    }
})
```

after this you should pass the call the state and pass param in ui-sref like below,

```
<a ui-sref="Parent.Child1({paramName: scopeName})">Click</a>
```

here scopeName is the name of the scope which have the value to param, if you want hard code a string, then you can pass in qoutes, ({paramName: 'some string'})

Comment: @aamir..i tried this earlier but i updated the question with solution that i was looking for..thank you for the reply.